# @Type annotation in Hibernate is not Working. I am using @SQLInsert

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have a model class in hibernate with a field with Calendar type. The corresponding DB column is of timestampwithtimezone(6). I am using custom @SQLInsert. The class looks like below-

```
@Entity
@SQLInsert("insert into EMPLOYEE (STARTDATETIME) values (TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(?,'DD-     MM-YY HH.MI.SS PM TZHTZM '))" )
@Table(
    name = "EMPLOYEE",
     )
public class Employee {
@Column(
        name = "STARTDATETIME",
        nullable = false
       )
@Type(type = "com.myPackage.TimeStampTypeImpl")
private Calendar startDateTime;

public Calendar getStartDateTime() {
    return this.startDateTime;        
}

public void setStartDateTime(Calendar startDateTime) {
    this.startDateTime = startDateTime;

}
}
```

In the class TimeStampTypeImpl which is implementing Usertype is doing the necessary conversion of Calendar to suitable string which is supposed to be given in the input parameter of the insert query, in nullSafeSet method. 
But the problem I am getting is- it seems that the the custome class TimestampImpl is not working- the nullSafeSet method is not getting called. So the insert query is failing.

The libraries I am using is-

hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar

hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar

hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar

Code in TimeStampTypeImpl :

```
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {

    Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
    log.debug("TIMESTAMPIMPL2");
    tring dateTime = getOracleFormattedTimeWithZone(cal);
    log.debug("TIMESTAMPIMPL3");
    st.setString(index, dateTime);

}

    private static String getOracleFormattedTimeWithZone(Calendar timeWithZone) {

    String dateFormat = "dd-MM-yy hh.mm.ss a Z";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    String dateTime = df.format(timeWithZone.getTime());
    System.out.println("()()()()()()()()()"+dateTime);
    return dateTime;
```

}

Comment: Can you add the sql generated? Why does column name and insert statement differs? **STARTDATE** in insert and **STARTDATETIME** in column definition?

Comment: sorry, I have edited the insert statement. both the column names are same. Exception is coming as 'logExceptions, ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required'. If I comment the @Type part, same exception comes which indicates the annotation is not working.

Comment: The converstion logic inside nullSafeSet is-                                        String dateFormat = "dd-MM-yy hh.mm.ss a Z";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        String dateTime = df.format(timeWithZone.getTime());
        System.out.println("()()()()()()()()()"+dateTime);
        return dateTime;

Comment: If you remove PM from the string 'DD-MM-YY HH.MI.SS PM TZHTZM' does it work? has the convertion logic PM output in the string, can you add an example output of the nullSafeSet?

Comment: Thanks @sgpalit. I found the problem. I did not override the nullsafeset correctly.I missed one argument.